# Web service should have permissions to read files on another server but can't?

Tags: c#, windows, web-services

I have developed a web service in c# and .Net framework 4.0 and published this to a server "A". This web services must read dbf tables hosted on a server "B". but I get the following error:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft] [ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver] File 'cctedia.dbf' does not exist.
    at ws_saldomatico_fpro.DetalleCtaCte (String str_rut) in c: \ Inetpub \ wwwroot \ WS_Saldomatico \ App_Code \ ws_saldomatico_fpro.cs: line 293
```

The file path is correct.  Another test that was performed was hosting the dbf file on the same server where the web service is published and this works fine.
Both servers are running Windows Server 2003.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It must be a problem of permissions. You must give the appropriate permissions to acces the file to the user which is running the WCF service. That user is the application pool user defined in IIS.

Comment: Rightly
grant read and write permissions to the NetworkService account on the folder and works fine
thanks;)

Comment: Please, mark as correct answer, to help other people with same problem.